# HTTP Basic Authentication in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, basic-authentication

I am trying to call an API in `AngularJS`. API has `HTTP Basic Authentication` with `username = admin` and `password = admin123`

This is how I am calling the API,

```
$http.get('https://example.com', {
    headers: {'Authorization': 'Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4xMjM='}
}).then(console.log("something"));
```

But, it is giving me `401 UnAuthorized` response. What is the recommended way to pass the username and password ? I am using `AngularJS 1`.

Error is showing,

```
OPTIONS https://example.com 401 ()

Failed to load https://example.com: Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 401.

Possibly unhandled rejection: {"data":null,"status":-1,"config":{"method":"GET","transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"jsonpCallbackParam":"callback","headers":{"Authorization":"Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4xMjM=","Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*"},"url":"https://example.com"},"statusText":"","xhrStatus":"error"}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're probably going to want to set the authorization headers at a more global level if all of your requests are going to need it. You can do this by adding

```
.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = '<Basic Auth Header>';
}]);
```

In your app config. To answer your actual question, I don't see anything specifically wrong with the code that you provided. Could you provide some information around what the server side is expecting and how it's reading the authorization?

Comment: From error messages, it seems that API is taking Option method only. I am using GET. Is that a problem.

Comment: I have updated the error log. Please check. Whenever you hit the URL it asks for username and password in a simple login form

Comment: Are you certain that the credentials you're using are correct? You could also try to make the request in the command line using something like CURL to see if it's an issue with the server or the angular client code.

Comment: When authenticate over https, NGINX or other webserver drops querystring auth; Try add `queryStringAuth: true` to your request in someway.